# Page specific javascript isn't being included. Is shown 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I work with pure JS and CSS and hence, I've removed the coffee-script and scss-rails from the GEMFILE.

All my javascript and css files have the extension of `.js` and `.css` respectively.

And those files are in following structure in their respective folders. I've removed `//= require_tree .` as well.

```
app
|___assets
    |__javascript 
    |__stylesheets
```

Now, in my `application.html.erb`, I have

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %> # Doesn't work!
```

The respective page specific stylesheet, i.e `post.css` is being loaded perfectly and it's path is `/assets/post.css?body=1`, but `post.js` is not loading and moreover, it's url is a bit weird.

It was like `/javascripts/post.js` and that was met with `404` error code. I can't get my head around this as the stylesheet works but the javascript is acting weird.

What would be the solution?

Comment: Does it work to do `<%= javascript_include_tag "#{params[:controller]}.js" %> `? (I know you shouldn't technically need to - http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag, but sometimes it's touchy)

Comment: have you added them to the /config/initializers/assets.rb file?